# Kafka topic stops receiving message

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I need to stop receiving message from producer when the schema in producer change. For example, producer-1 send message to topic in schema-1, after that producer-2 send message to the same topic in schema-2, so I need to stop receive messages from producer-1. Can I set some properties or what can I do in this case?

Comment: You might consider using Confluent Schema Registry: https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/index.html 

The purpose of this tool is exactly you are talking about (+ different compatibility modes).

Comment: I consider compatibility mode also, so now I can write different schema to one topic. But I need to stop receiving message from first schema, when I wright messages in second schema. Maybe you can specify what I need to read in this documentation?

Answer (score 0):

What is your use case? You could add a version property in your data. On the consumer side, you can then process messages with a specific version value and filter/drop rest of the messages.